# How can I open the Gmail reply composer in a separate window?

Tags: gmail

Gmail launched a new composer interface today. In the new interface, I can't figure out how to pop out a draft reply into a separate window. Sometimes it's nice to have the extra space.

Is this possible?

This is what my compose screen looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how to do it as of the Oct 2018 version of gmail. It requires 2 steps:

1. `shift + r` or `shift + click Reply` to "Reply with Pop Out". This will open the reply in a "pop out dialog", but it's still in the same browser tab.
2. Next, find the "Exit full-screen" button in the upper right corner.

If you do `shift + click [Exit full-screen]`, it will open the Reply window in a new browser **window**.

If you do `ctrl + click [Exit full-screen]` (or `cmd` on mac), it will open the Reply window in a new browser **tab**.

[image]

Comment: This is a genuis trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

There are two ways to do this:

1. From within the inline message, you can start a separate conversation:
   [image: Start]
   and then press this arrow:
   [image]
2. Press the new window arrow all the way on top of the email thread:
   [image]

Answer (score 3):

In the black bar at the top of the new Compose window there is a diagonal arrow (in between the Minimize and Close icons). This works only for new emails for which you hit the red "Compose" button. This will open a new window.

Edit:
For replies, there is no way to do this AFAIK. The simplest workaround is to hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> then Click. Otherwise you'll need to revert to the old Compose functionality.

Comment: I have no black bar or diagonal arrow. See the screenshot in my edit.

Comment: Ahhh, sorry, didn't realize you were talking about a reply. Edited my answer accordingly

Answer (score 3):

The best solution is holding Shift while clicking the "fullscreen" arrow for the email reply or draft you are currently composing.

Answer (score 2):

In the "inline reply", click on the reply drop down list to choose the type of reply. From that list, choose "Start separate conversation".

Comment: Weirdly named--I tested this, and it doesn't actually start a separate conversation (my reply showed up in the same conversation). But it does solve my issue perfectly, so thanks.

Comment: GMail must have updated yet again, as you can now choose "Pop out reply" from that reply drop down list. It's still in the same location as your answer, so +1.

Comment: This answer is obsolete at this time.

Answer (score 1):

All answers as on date require use of mouse to get desired result. My answer requires keyboard only.

Make sure keyboard shortcuts are turned on in gmail settings.

Right click the gmail thread/conversation you want to reply to; by using right-click button on keyboard or using Shift+F10 if such button does not exist on your keyboard.

There you will find the first entry in context menu is automatically highlighted but we need to reach 'Open in New Window' at the bottom entry. Simply press Up arrow key once and then press enter.

[image: Context Menu]

The desired conversation will open up in new window.

Thereafter, press a to Reply-all; r to Reply; f to forward.

Note: Sometimes, right-click will conflict between browser and gmail so keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

As of a few minutes ago on Firefox Opensuse, only one of wisbucky's two alternatives above worked for me.  The path starting from `shift + click Reply` leads to the same constricted textbox to enter the reply.  What worked was:

This is how to do it as of January 14, 2019 on Firefox on Opensuse:

`shift + r`

to "Reply with Pop Out". This will open the reply in a "pop out dialog", but it's still in the same browser tab.

Next, find the "Exit full-screen" button in the upper right corner.

If you do

`shift + click [Exit full-screen]`

it opens the Reply window in a new browser window, and I can compose and view my draft answer using nearly the full display area of the browser.

Answer (score -1):

The pop-out thing, a small diagonal arrow, is up at the top of the whole mail thread, not in the in-line compose window. Pop out the thread and the compose window comes with it.

Comment: I would add a bit more context.

Answer (score -3):

hold the shift key when clicking on Reply